# History of Brahmin's diet

Tags: history, brahmins, food

What is the history of brahmana diet?
Brahmins are generally vegetarians but there are some exceptions to it such as Pancha-Gauda Brahmans, Kashmiri Brahmans, and Oriya Brahmins?

So why is there so much difference?

Answer (score 1):

I can provide only a partial answer. In the Tantras, there are contradictory opinions regarding a brahmin's eating of non-vegeterian food. The Varahi-Tantra says

> A brahmin should never even think of eating fish, meat and wine.

Meru-Tantra says

> A brahmin should never eat meat or wine.

On the otherhand, the Kamakhya-Tantra says

> Following the order of Lord Shiva, the Indian (Jamvu-dvipabasi) brahmins should never worship with pasu-bhava (ie he should eat fish, meat and wine).

The Kali-vilas Tantra says

> Nobody should eat meat,fish and wine in the age of kali.

Reconciling the views, the Bhava-Chudamani Tantra says

> Meat, fish, etc can be taken only by the fallen brahmins.

So I think ultimately the decision to eat these or not would depend on (a) the family tradition and (b) the instructions of the Guru.

None is allowed to eat unoffered meat or fish by the way.

Reference :Sastramulak Bharatiya Saktisadhana, Upendrakumar Das, RMIC,Vol 2, page 641-642.